# SQL: exclude users where at least one row is matching

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database of users (id, name) which is connected to database of their purchases (id, userId, price). 
What I want to do is to find all users who didn't make a purchase with price 500. At first I though about such query, but it would return all rows where price is not 500, not the users themselves.

```
select * from purchase p
join user u on u.id = p.userId
and price != 500
```

Does somebody have an idea how to group it so only the users who NEVER did 500 purchase would show up?

Comment: You could use `where not exists()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to group by the user and take only those groups having no `purchase` with a `price` of  `500`

```
select u.id, u.name
from user u
left join purchase p on u.id = p.userId
group by u.id, u.name
having sum(p.price = 500) = 0
```

Comment: Wouldn't sum(p.price = 500) cause adding all the prices together? What I need is single purchase of singe value 500.

Comment: `sum(p.price)` would add them together. `sum(p.price = 500)` adds up how many times this condition was `true`. You can also write `sum(case when p.price = 500 then 1 else 0 end)`